# OpenGL SegFault in glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

My call to `glDrawElements` is producing a segmentation fault. If I scrap the indices and use `glDrawArrays` everything in my vertex buffer is drawn. So my assumption is that the error is in the way I'm populating the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but I don't see the problem.

I have a sphere class that's producing vertices and indices for a sphere. I then just the following code to setup the vbo, vao etc:

```
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct VertexData) * sphere.GetVertices()->size(), sphere.GetVertices()->data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, normal));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, tcoords));

    GLuint ibo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * sphere.GetIndices()->size(), sphere.GetIndices()->data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

..in which I can't see anything wrong.

My drawing is then done like this:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

float t = watch.GetElapsedTimePeriod().count();
float rotation = 0.5/1000.0*t;
rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(rotationMatrix,rotation,glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 modelMatrix = perspectiveMatrix * viewMatrix * rotationMatrix * identitymatrix;

glUseProgram(shaderprogram);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "mvpmatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));

glBindVertexArray(vao);
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<GLushort>> p = sphere.GetIndices();
size_t tt = p->size();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,tt,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
//glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,(*sphere.GetVertices()).size());
glBindVertexArray(0);

glUseProgram(0);

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlglHandler);
```

You can see my commented out `glDrawArrays` call that succeeds if I use it (and don't setup the index buffer in the top code). (It's `GL_POINTS` so that I can see every vertex being drawn.)

I've noted that if I generate less vertices in my sphere the program doesn't crash. So at first I thought it was the use of `GLushort` as the type for my indices, but there aren't that many vertices being produced for it to be a problem. I tested by using GLuint as well but that didn't do anything.

Next, I've noted that if I use less than the size of my indices vector (being returned from the sphere) I can get it to work; but it has to be about 1/6th of the size (and of course only about 1/6th of my sphere's triangles are drawn.

I've looked through the rest of my code as well to see if I'm writing past an array or anything and quite simply it's only in the openGL code where I'm doing anything with arrays and pointers.

Because I'm able to remove the index array and see it working, I'm convinced that it has something to do with this; but I cannot work it out.

Oh and finally, the VertexData structure looks like this:

```
struct VertexData
{
    GLdouble position[4];
    GLfloat color[3];
    GLfloat normal[3];
    GLfloat tcoords[2];
};
```

## **Massive Edit**

I've since removed all of my C++ encapsulation and produced this code which gives me the same error. I'm at a complete loss to see where trying to access private memory, nothing looks like it's overflowing to me:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <utilities.hpp>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/sdl.h>
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

struct VertexData
{
    GLdouble position[4];
    GLfloat color[3];
    GLfloat normal[3];
    GLfloat tcoords[2];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_GLContext context;
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("unable to initialise video");

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 4);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);

        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SpaceEngine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(!window)
            throw std::runtime_error("unable to create window");

        context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

        SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

        GLenum glewErr = glewInit();
        if(glewErr != GLEW_OK)
        {
            SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            throw std::runtime_error(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glewGetErrorString(glewErr)));
        }

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        std::vector<VertexData> vertices;
        std::vector<GLushort> indices;
        int rings = 200;
        int sectors = 200;
        float radius = 1.0;

        if(rings < 2)
            rings = 2;
        if(sectors < 2)
            sectors = 2;
        while(rings * sectors >= std::numeric_limits<GLushort>::max())
        {
            rings /= 2;
            sectors /= 2;
        }

        const GLuint polyCountXPitch = rings+1;

        GLuint level = 0;

        for(GLuint p1 = 0; p1 < sectors-1; ++p1)
        {
            for(GLuint p2 = 0; p2 < rings-1; ++p2)
            {
                GLuint curr = level + p2;
                indices.push_back(curr + polyCountXPitch);
                indices.push_back(curr);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1);
                indices.push_back(curr + polyCountXPitch);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1);
                indices.push_back(curr + 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            }

            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1);
            indices.push_back(level + rings);

            indices.push_back(level + rings - 1 + polyCountXPitch);
            indices.push_back(level + rings);
            indices.push_back(level + rings + polyCountXPitch);

            level += polyCountXPitch;
        }

        const GLuint polyCountSq = polyCountXPitch * sectors;           //top point
        const GLuint polyCountSq1 = polyCountSq + 1;                    //bottom point
        const GLuint polyCountSqM1 = (sectors - 1) * polyCountXPitch;   //last rows first index

        for(GLuint p2 = 0; p2 < rings - 1; ++p2)
        {
            indices.push_back(polyCountSq);
            indices.push_back(p2 + 1);
            indices.push_back(p2);

            indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + p2);
            indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + p2 + 1);
            indices.push_back(polyCountSq1);
        }

        indices.push_back(polyCountSq);
        indices.push_back(rings);
        indices.push_back(rings - 1);

        indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1 + rings - 1);
        indices.push_back(polyCountSqM1);
        indices.push_back(polyCountSq1);

        const GLdouble angleX = 2 * pi() / rings;
        const GLdouble angleY = pi() / sectors;

        GLuint i = 0;
        GLdouble axz;
        GLdouble ay = 0;

        vertices.resize(polyCountXPitch * sectors + 2);
        for(GLuint y = 0; y < sectors; ++y)
        {
            ay += angleY;
            const GLdouble sinay = std::sin(ay);
            axz = 0;

            for(GLuint xz = 0; xz < rings; ++xz)
            {
                const glm::vec3 pos((radius * std::cos(axz) * sinay),radius * std::cos(ay), radius * std::sin(axz) * sinay);
                glm::vec3 normal = pos;
                normal = glm::normalize(normal);

                GLuint tu = 0.5f;
                if(y == 0)
                {
                    if(normal.y != -1.0f && normal.y != 1.0f)
                        tu = std::acos(glm::clamp<GLdouble>(normal.x/sinay, -1.0f, 1.0f)) * 0.5 * (1.0f/pi());
                    if(normal.z < 0.0f)
                        tu = 1 - tu;
                }
                else
                    tu = vertices[i-polyCountXPitch].tcoords[0];

                VertexData v;
                v.color[0] = 1;
                v.color[1] = 1;
                v.color[2] = 1;
                v.position[0] = pos.x;
                v.position[1] = pos.y;
                v.position[2] = pos.z;
                v.position[3] = 1.0f;
                v.normal[0] = normal.x;
                v.normal[1] = normal.y;
                v.normal[2] = normal.z;
                v.tcoords[0] = tu;
                v.tcoords[1] = ay * (1.0f/pi());
                vertices.at(i) = v;

                ++i;
                axz += angleX;
            }

            vertices.at(i) = vertices.at(i - rings);
            vertices.at(i).tcoords[0] = 1.0f;
            ++i;
        }

        VertexData v;
        v.color[0] = 1;
        v.color[1] = 1;
        v.color[2] = 1;
        v.position[0] = 0;
        v.position[1] = radius;
        v.position[2] = 0;
        v.position[3] = 1.0f;
        v.normal[0] = 0;
        v.normal[1] = 1;
        v.normal[2] = 0;
        v.tcoords[0] = 0.5f;
        v.tcoords[1] = 0.0f;
        vertices.at(i) = v;
        ++i;
        v.position[1] = -radius;
        v.normal[1] = -1.0f;
        v.tcoords[1] = 1.0f;
        vertices.at(i) = v;

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct VertexData) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, position));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, color));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, normal));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(struct VertexData, tcoords));

        GLuint ibo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        GLuint shader1,shader2;
        std::ifstream file("tutorial2.vert");
        if(!file)
            throw std::runtime_error("The file tutorial2.vert was not opened");
        else
        {
            std::string fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

            shader1 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            std::string fail = "glCreateShader failed using " + GL_VERTEX_SHADER;

            if(!shader1)
                throw std::runtime_error(fail.c_str());

            const GLchar* contents[1];
            contents[0] = fileContents.c_str();
            glShaderSource(shader1, 1, contents, NULL);

            glCompileShader(shader1);
            int compiled;
            glGetShaderiv(shader1, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
            if(compiled == 0)
            {
                int maxLength;
                glGetShaderiv(shader1, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
                char* vertexInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader1, maxLength, &maxLength, vertexInfoLog);
                throw std::runtime_error("Shader failed to compile:\n>\t" + std::string(vertexInfoLog));
            }
        }
        std::ifstream file2("tutorial2.frag");
        if(!file2)
            throw std::runtime_error("The file tutorial2.frag was not opened");
        else
        {
            std::string fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file2)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

            shader2 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            std::string fail = "glCreateShader failed using " + GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
            if(!shader2)
                throw std::runtime_error(fail.c_str());

            const GLchar* contents[1];
            contents[0] = fileContents.c_str();
            glShaderSource(shader2, 1, contents, NULL);

            glCompileShader(shader2);
            int compiled;
            glGetShaderiv(shader2, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
            if(compiled == 0)
            {
                int maxLength;
                glGetShaderiv(shader2, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
                char* vertexInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader2, maxLength, &maxLength, vertexInfoLog);
                throw std::runtime_error("Shader failed to compile:\n>\t" + std::string(vertexInfoLog));
            }
        }

        GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
        if(!program)
            throw std::runtime_error("glCreateProgram failed");

        glAttachShader(program, shader1);
        glAttachShader(program, shader2);

        glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "in_Position");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_Color");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "in_Normal");
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 3, "in_UV");

        glLinkProgram(program);
        int IsLinked;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&IsLinked);
        if(IsLinked == 0)
        {
           int maxLength;
           glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
           char* shaderProgramInfoLog = new char[maxLength];
           glGetProgramInfoLog(program, maxLength, &maxLength, shaderProgramInfoLog);
           throw std::runtime_error("Program failed to link:\n>\t" + std::string(shaderProgramInfoLog) + "");
        }

        glDetachShader(program, shader1);
        glDetachShader(program, shader2);

        bool done = false;

        while(!done)
        {
            SDL_Event event;
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                switch(event.type)
                {
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                    switch(event.window.event)
                    {
                    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(program);

            glBindVertexArray(vao);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

            glBindVertexArray(0);

            glUseProgram(0);

            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
            }

        glUseProgram(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glDeleteProgram(program);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();

        std::cout << "all good in the hood" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\t" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

precision highp float;

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;
in vec3 in_Normal;
in vec2 in_UV;

uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;

out vec3 ex_Color;
void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = in_Position;

    ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

And my Frag shader:

```
#version 150

precision highp float;

in  vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);
}
```

## **EDIT2**

I've even tried outputing a line of text to a file and iterate through each triangle in my indices 1 by 1. If I run it a few times I find the segfault happens at different points in the indices array. The vertex that the index is looking up is within bounds of my vertices array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tt; i+=3)
{
    file << "attempting " << i/3 << std::endl;
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,i,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlglHandler);
}
```

So this tells me that I'm trying to access a index that is outside of the bounds from what I sent to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` but again, I cannot see the problem.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you have invalid indices in the index array. Did you check all the index values, and confirm that none of them are >= the number of vertices?

Comment: Hi @RetoKoradi, thanks for your reply. Yes, after sphere generation I output all of the vertices and indices to .txt files and looked through them.

Comment: I'd still add some check for that in the code. It's a lot of indices to check and you just need to miss one of them.

Comment: @PerroAzul At the beginning of my sphere generation I'm checking to make sure that the number of vertices won't go over the bounds of GLushort, and if they do to keep dividing by 2 until they fit.

I can add a call to std::min_element and std::max_element on the indices vertex and see that the smallest value is 0 and largest is 40201, which works perfectly fine against the vertices vector size of 40202.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in using GL_DOUBLE for the vertices. Changing to GL_FLOAT seems to have done the trick.

You need to use `glVertexAttribLPointer` when using double.

To use glVertexAttribLPointer meaningfully would require you to re-write a line in your shader (in dvec4 in_Position)

Answer (score 4):

Your use of VAOs looks correct. Nevertheless may I suggest that you explicitly add a glBindBuffer on the index buffer before doing the glDrawElements call, i.e.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<GLushort>> p = sphere.GetIndices();
size_t tt = p->size();

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,tt,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

---

Note that even today VAOs are not very much optimized and changing the VAO binding may mean a performance hit. Valve for example benchmarked it and as of now still has the codepaths using multiple VAOs disabled in their Source engine. Until this changes the recommended way is to just bind the buffer objects themself, and for OpenGL profiles that mandate a VAO to create and bind that once per context and then just ignore it in further operations.

Comment: Hi @datenwolf, thanks for your reply. I had already tried that as I was thinking that maybe I was misinterpreting the openGL docs and how VAOs work. It didn't help.

I had no idea about the performance of VAOs; I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is part of the VAO state, so binding it is redundant and will only hurt performance. @datenwolf, do you have a link to recent data on that VAO claim from Steam? I can't think of a reason why using VAOs should not be at least as fast as setting up the state manually. The whole idea of VAOs is to make state setup more efficient. And it works that way if they are properly implemented.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Talk "Porting Source to Linux, Lessons Learned" http://adrienb.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/PortingSourceToLinux.pdf – Slide 57. I'm fully aware that rebinding the element array buffer should be redundant, but sometimes you have to try out these things to eliminate the possibility that you're mislead by a driver bug.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for the link. Interesting presentation. The "slower on all implementations" claim is definitely false, though. Either they're doing something wrong, or they haven't looked very far.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Well, they have their own tech and very good connections to all GPU developers. I highly recommend their postmortems on porting the Source engine to OpenGL and Linux, because then they had a very unique collaboration with driver developers, where parts of the open source Linux drivers got optimizations done by Valve staff and the Source engine got tuned a bit by the driver devs. I conjecture that the performance of VAOs depends strongly on the usage pattern and probably also on the data / batch ratio.

Comment: Of course they did. I hadn't heard that before, but it brought a smile to my face.